# How to get RingCentral Live Reports data using the API?

Tags: ringcentral

When getting the call log data using below URL:

`https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/call-log?view=Simple&dateFrom='+Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd')+'&page=1&perPage=10000`

This data is not matching with the inbound and outbound count in [Live Reports](https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/9217?language=en_US).

Is any way there to get Live Reports data using an API call?

Answer (score 1):

Live Reports provide graphical representations from some internal metrics and metadata and are totally independent system and not sure if it uses data from RingCentral call log.

The API you are using is of call log with parameters and it will be not same as Live Report data and will have some difference in both the output.

Answer (score 0):

RingCentral Live Reports uses Call Session Notification (CSN) events as the underlying data for its metrics and so you can replicate the results by subscribing to the following CSN event filters:

```
[
  "/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/telephony/sessions",
  "/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/~/telephony/sessions"
]
```

Read more here:

- [Account Telephony Sessions Event](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Account-Telephony-Sessions-Event)
- [Extension Telephony Sessions Event](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Extension-Telephony-Sessions-Event)